# Поиск и удаление в vim по шаблону

Tags: vim

Есть json файл в котором встречаются последовательности:

```
[
0.0,
0.0,
0.0
...
]
```

Как удалить такие массивы с 0.0?

Comment: массивы разной длинны целиком заполненные только `0.0`?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Длина у всех разная. Цели удалить все сразу нету. Можно по одному. Я имею ввиду что таких массивов в файле много.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно такие массивы можно найти с помощью такого паттерна:

```
\[\(0\.0\|,\| \|\n\)\+\]
```

Ну а дальше: как вам заблагарассудиться, например если хотите их заменить на пустой массив, то:

```
%s/\[\(0\.0\|,\| \|\n\)\+\]/\[\]
```

Comment: Не может найти.

Comment: @D.Ivan в таком случае уточните что вы делаете и образец данных предоставте

Comment: Выдает - E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &

Comment: Разобрался пропустили / в начале. Спасибо.

Comment: @D.Ivan незачто

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, по-моему, слэш не в начале пропущен, а в конце (второй команды)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не понимаю о чем вы

Comment: ну, синтаксис команды `s` вроде бы стандартный для всех реализаций движков рег. выражений: `s/что/на что/`. три ограничивающих символа (в данном случае слэшей). а у вас только два.

Comment: Третий не обязательный